# How to call maximize events manually

Tags: c#, winforms, maximize-window

I am having one form, and I want that to load in the maximized state. How do I call the windows maximize event on form load?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not call any events. Simply set the `WindowState` property to maximized:

```
Form form = new Form();
form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
form.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 6):

You should set the [WindowState property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate.aspx) of the form on the load of the form. Set it to `FormWindowState.Maximized`.

Answer (score 3):

Just set the form's [WindowsState property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate.aspx) to maximized. Then it should start up Maximized.